# Filtering elements of layer with active element of QGIS atlas with geometry functions?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, atlas

I'm working with QGIS 2.18

In a print composer I can filter the elements of a layer based on the attribute of the active element of an atlas. For example, show only the cities (points) of a state (polygons), when the state layer is the coverage layer of the atlas. I'm using rule-based symbolization, where both layers have a common attribute.

I would like to know if they can be filtered in the same way, but using geometry functions like the intersect. I would like to filter the elements of a layer, which intersect with the elements of the active element of the coverage layer of an atlas.

I'm trying with the intersects function, but I can not get the correct syntax.

Is it possible to make this query?

Comment: I'm sorry, I find the solution.  intersects(   transform( $geometry, 25829, 25830) ,  geometry( @atlas_feature ) )   . In my problem I need to transform the SRC.

Answer (score 1):

This code should be the correct answer to your question:

[% aggregate('LAYER_NAME','concatenate',"ATTRIBUTE",
              within($geometry,@atlas_geometry), ',') %]

Comment: if you only need the filter term within($geometry,@atlas_geometry) will do the trick.